# Is the set of strings $0^{2k}10^{2k}10^{k}$ for $k \geq 0$ context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

I am able to solve $0^{k}10^{k}10^{j}$ where $ k < j$. and I was able to see that this is also a concatenation of two strings. How to do it for $0^{2k}10^{2k}10^{k}$ for $k \ge 0$?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, neither of your examples is a CFL.

Comment: You are right, I neglected to mention it was a unrestricted grammar.

Comment: If you neglected to mention something, please edit the question to correct it.  We want questions to be self-contained.  Comments exist to help you improve the question; people shouldn't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Steven please delete your obsolete comments and check whether edit caught everything crucial. In the future please make sure that your question is self-contained and clear. Please consider accepting skankhunt42's answer as he already answered two questions.

Comment: The title of your question doesn't make any sense and bears little relation to the body. Please state the question clearly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no context free grammar that can accept those two sets. You can show that using the pumping lemma for CFLs.

Suppose $L = \{x \in \{0,1\}^* \mid x = 0^{2k}10^{2k}10^{k}, k \geq 0 \}$
Let $n$ be the pumping lemma constant.
I can choose $z = 0^{2n}10^{2n}10^{n} $. Clearly $|z| \geq n$. 
Now let $z = uvwxy$ be any decomposition of $z$ such that $|vwx| \leq n$ and $|vx| > 0$.

**Case 1**: Either $v$ or $x$ contains at least one $1$. Then the string $z^\prime = uv^0wx^0y = uwy$ contains strictly less that two $1$s, so $z^\prime \notin L$.

**Case 2**: Both $v$ and $x$ entirely consist of $0$s. Note that since $|vwx| \leq n$, therefore $vwx$ can cover at most 2 'parts' (contiguous substring of $0$s) of the original string $z$. So, we again choose the string $z^\prime = uv^0wx^0y = uwy$. The third 'part' of the string which is not covered by $vwx$ will then violate the condition and $z^\prime \neq 0^{2m}10^{2m}10^m $. So, $z^\prime \notin L$.

So, $L$ is *not* a context-free language. A similar proof can be given for $0^{k}10^{k}10^{2k}$. I have no idea how you were able to 'solve' this one!

### EDIT

The question was edited from context-free grammars to context sensitive grammars. The language $L = \{x \in \{0,1\}^* \mid x = 0^{2k}10^{2k}10^{k}, k \geq 0 \}$ can indeed be generated from a context-sensitive grammar.

$$
\begin{align}
S^\prime &\rightarrow WS \\
S  &\rightarrow LRS0 \mid 1 \\
RL &\rightarrow RM \\
RM &\rightarrow LM \\
LM &\rightarrow LR \\
WL &\rightarrow WV \\
WV &\rightarrow LV \\
LV &\rightarrow LW \\
W &\rightarrow 1 \\
L1 &\rightarrow 001 \\
L0 &\rightarrow 000 \\
1R &\rightarrow 100 \\
0R &\rightarrow 000
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Maybe my terminiology is wrong but for this one, $0^{k}10^{k}10^{2k}$ all I did was the following.

S -> AB
A -> 0RA2 | 012| empty
R0 -> 0R
R1 -> 11
B -> 2B | 2

Maybe I should of mentioned it was unrestricted because this is the solution to this question.

But now that I said this, I realize my error I made and will edit it...

However the $0^{2k}10^{2k}10^{k}$ is an accurate problem

Comment: The problem I solved should read $0^{i}10^{i}10^{j}$ where i < j.

My edit time ran out but just needed to make it clear.

I see how pumping lemma proves this wrong, but does it being unrestricted change this solution at all?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by unrestricted. If you're talking about [unrestricted grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_grammar), then yes it can be generated by an unrestricted grammar.

Comment: Yup! Thanks, sorry :/ I didn't know unrestricted was used for other things, but yeah unrestricted grammars

Comment: Your context-sensitive grammar is not context-sensitive (which allows to replace one non terminal without modifying its context).  It is a non-contracting one. There is an algorithm to transform non-contracting grammar into context-sensitive one so there is no difference in expressive power but context-sensitive grammar tends to have even more rules.

Comment: @AProgrammer Thanks, I have edited the answer.

Comment: `The question was edited from context-free grammars to context sensitive grammars` not exactly: it has been re-tagged. The title as of rev. 5 reads `context-free`, again.